# Configuring Microsoft Windows Live claims in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have followed this link to configure Microsoft Windows Live login
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Microsoft+Windows+Live

In WSO2 log, I can see the Remote Claim that I received from IDP

```
[2016-05-03 15:47:14,027] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.claims.impl.DefaultClaimHandler} -  Executing c
laim handler. isFederatedClaims = true and remote claims = [emails:{"business":null,"personal":null,"preferred":"xyz@gmail.com","account":"xyz@gmail.com"},gender:null,name:,last_name:,id:048ea1532ffb8000,locale:en_US,first_name:,
```

]

I am just wondering how to map the email to local claim URI http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress because the remote claim contains nested tag (emails:{ business: ..., personal: ... }).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the remote claim contains a nested tag, you have to extend DefaultClaimHandler and write a claim handler to support nested tag.

You can configure new claim hanlder in

IS_HOME/repository/conf/identity/application­-authentication.xml

(in 'ApplicationAuthentication.Extensions.ClaimHandler' element.)

`<ClaimHandler>com.wso2.sample.claim.handler.CustomClaimHandler</ClaimHandler>`

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Here is a question based on my understanding. If I have configured multiple federated authenticator and the claims are nested for most of them, how do I wire multiple custom claim handles